# How to find the value of this keystrokes?

Tags: bash, keyboard, xinput

When i heared about `xinput` usage from one of my friend. I tried its for recording my keystrokes

```
 xinput list id 7
```

Here 7 is my keyboard id, Then its generate following value.When i press the key and released time.
I cant understand what the numbers indicates .I cant able to confirm this belongs to ascii or anyother things?
Please guide me to understand this

> key release 36
>
> key press   43
>
> hkey release 43
>
> key press   38
>
> akey press   31
>
> ikey release 38
>
> key release 31
>
> key press   37
>
> key press   54

Updated:

I tested with the word

> hai

Which return following output

> key release 36
>
> key press   43
>
> hkey release 43
>
> key press   38
>
> akey release 38
>
> key press   31
>
> ikey release 31
>
> key press   37

here 36 and 37 are starting and end the endpoint.

> hai = 43 38 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the virtual-key codes in their decimal value. From your example `key release 36` means the `Home` button was released. As a reference you can find the codes [here](http://cherrytree.at/misc/vk.htm)

You can find their hexadecimal value [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)

As per uses for this, for example, they are used in Javascript(as decimal value but i'm sure they can be used in decimal/hexa/constant name) in order to listen for a key press/release in order to do a specific action like minimize a menu. Of course there are a ton of other uses for it.

Comment: Hi ,@pungk  Question updated with some modification. The link you provided with codes, which does not match with this execution

Comment: Are you trying to remap your keyboard? That is just the keycode mapped for those keys.  You can check your mapping in the xmodmap/xkb files [link](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html)